# Access RapidSMS application

Tags: python, django

i download and install new RapidSMS python app in local and tested the eg Ping & Pong. Its working fine. But after closing terminal and browser i can't access(127.0.0.1:8000) the application in browser. How i can run that application again?

Thanks.

Comment: Same way you ran it for the first time :-). Open the terminal -> go to the project directory -> then fire command "python manage.py runserver"

Comment: i tried this, but it shows error like this
ImportError: No module named rapidsms.contrib.default

Comment: virtual environment is running?

Comment: try this, open python interpreter (python in terminal) then try to import the rapidsms.contrib.default module

Comment: @anurgal How can run virtual environment?

Comment: @user2198047 - please share the link of tutorial you followed for initial setup, so that I can help you accordingly.

Comment: its working now. But i have some doubts in implementing rapidsms. If anybody can share skype id, who are implemented rapidsms.?